# While loop in C iterates twice before asking for user input

Tags: c, while-loop

I am trying to make a `while` loop that reads questions from a file and gets a users input and loops through then until it reaches the end of the questions file.

My issue is that the loop iterates twice before asking the user for input.

```
  fp = fopen("questions.txt","r");
  fp2 = fopen("answers.txt","w");

  char buff[255];
  char input[255];

  while (fscanf(fp,"%s",buff)!=EOF) 
  {
      printf(" %s", buff);
      printf("answer:");
      fgets(input,256,stdin);
      fprintf(fp2,"\n");
      fprintf(fp2,"%s",buff);
      fprintf(fp2,"\n");
      fprintf(fp2,"%s",input );
  };
```

Comment: I dont't find any mistake in your code in `gcc`

Comment: Most probably, you have an unread *newline* (`\n`) in `stdin` when running this code, most probably from some previous `scanf()` that didn't match it.

Comment: note it's **very difficult** to use the `scanf()` family of functions correctly -- I suggest reading my [beginners' guide away from scanf](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) :)

Comment: Tip: when having trouble with strings, print them with sentinels to more quickly see unexpected leading and trailing whitespace.  Example: `fprintf(fp2,"%s",input );` --> `fprintf(fp2,"<%s>",input );`

Comment: Due to buffering, output to `stdout` may not appear when you expect.  Use `printf("answer:"); fflush(stdout); fgets(input,256,stdin);` to insure output is seen before the question.  This may not solve your issue as other things may contribute.  Post sample input used and output seen and expected to add clarity to the question, a  [MCVE], to receive a quality answer.

Comment: Can you show the output you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like:

```
char question[SIZE];
char answer[SIZE];

FILE * fin = fopen("questions.txt", "r");
FILE * fout = fopen("answers.txt", "w");

while (fgets(question, SIZE, fin) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", question);
    fgets(answer, SIZE, stdin);
    fputs(answer, fout);
}
```